What aren't my custom css buttons submitting with radio inputs in Rshiny application?
I am fairly new to using Rshiny and am trying to use styled css to make a multiple choice looking test. This will connect with a backend to effectively track all submissions (think: google forms). When I run this code, the submission tracks the text input perfectly fine, but doesn't save the submissions with the radio buttons. All I've seen online is that radios are best to be used without css as it can be finicky. How do I fix this application?
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

  #Use CSS to style each button so that it looks like a scantron
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .inline-radio-buttons .radio-inline input[type='radio'] {
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
      }
      .inline-radio-buttons .radio-inline label {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 30%;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      .inline-radio-buttons .radio-inline input[type='radio']:checked + label {
        background-color: #007bff;
        color: white;
        border-color: #007bff;
      }
    "))
  ),

  #Application Title
  titlePanel("This is your test"),

  #Sidebar with some test prep prelim questions and some actual questions
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
          
               # textInput("firstname", "Name:"),
               # textInput("email", "Email:"),
               # textInput("date", "Date:"),
               # textInput("testID", "Test ID:"),

               # Question 1
               div(class = "inline-radio-buttons",
                   # span("Q1:", style = "margin-right: 0px;"),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q1a", name = "question1", value = "A"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q1a", "A")
                   ),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q1b", name = "question1", value = "B"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q1b", "B")
                   ),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q1c", name = "question1", value = "C"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q1c", "C")
                   ),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q1d", name = "question1", value = "D"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q1d", "D")
                   ),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q1e", name = "question1", value = "E"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q1e", "E")
                   )
               ),

               # Question 2
               div(class = "inline-radio-buttons",
                   # span("Q2:", style = "margin-right: 0px;"),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q2f", name = "question2", value = "F"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q2f", "F")
                   ),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q2g", name = "question2", value = "G"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q2g", "G")
                   ),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q2h", name = "question2", value = "H"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q2h", "H")
                   ),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q2j", name = "question2", value = "J"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q2j", "J")
                   ),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q2k", name = "question2", value = "K"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q2k", "K")
                   )
               ),

               # Question 3
               div(class = "inline-radio-buttons",
                   # span("Q3:", style = "margin-right: 0px;"),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q3a", name = "question3", value = "A"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q3a", "A")
                   ),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q3b", name = "question3", value = "B"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q3b", "B")
                   ),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q3c", name = "question3", value = "C"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q3c", "C")
                   ),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q3d", name = "question3", value = "D"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q3d", "D")
                   ),
                   div(class = "radio-inline",
                       tags$input(type = "radio", id = "q3e", name = "question3", value = "E"),
                       tags$label(`for` = "q3e", "E")
                   )
               ),


               actionButton("submit", "Submit")
           
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           div(class = "centered-content",
               textOutput("confirmation")
           )
    )
  )
)


#server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  #test submissions yield Null - issue!!!
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    print(input$question1)
    print(input$question2)
    print(input$question3)
  })
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    # Gather responses with default values for missing inputs
    response <- data.frame(
      Name = ifelse(nchar(input$firstname) > 0, input$firstname, NA),
      Email = ifelse(nchar(input$email) > 0, input$email, NA),
      Date = ifelse(nchar(input$date) > 0, input$date, NA),
      TestID = ifelse(nchar(input$testID) > 0, input$testID, NA),
      question1 = ifelse(!is.null(input$question1) && input$question1 != "", input$question1, NA),
      question2 = ifelse(!is.null(input$question2) && input$question2 != "", input$question2, NA),
      question3 = ifelse(!is.null(input$question3) && input$question3 != "", input$question3, NA),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  
    # Ensure the data.frame has at least one row
    # if (nrow(response) > 0) {
      # Determine if the CSV file exists
      file_exists <- file.exists("responses.csv")

      # Append responses to the CSV file
      write.table(response, "responses.csv", sep = ",", append = file_exists,
                  col.names = !file_exists, row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)
      output$confirmation <- renderText("Thank you for your submission!")
    } else {
      output$confirmation <- renderText("Please complete all questions.")
    }
  })
}

Every button input was null, even when testing pre-submission.

Please edit your question in order to provide a minimal, reproducible example . Your code is on the one hand not reproducible (if commented and is necessary, also after correction errors in the app - check this before you post it) and also it is not minimal, for your issue description it is not necessary to provide 15 items, provide the shortest code necessary.

"doesn't save the submissions with the radio buttons" - do you mean the backend isn't saving those values or that they are never sent in the first place?

When creating cutom inputs you have to care about binding. Why don't you use shiny::radioButtons() and style them?
